# Discretization of second order nonlinear ODE using finite difference approximation not correct

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

I have the differential equation 
$$y'' + x(y^2)' - 2y^2 = g(x) \Longleftrightarrow y'' + x2yy'-2y^2 = g(x).$$
Using finite-difference approximations
$$y''(x_m) \approx \frac{Y_{m-1} - 2Y_m + Y_{m+1}}{\Delta x^2},$$
$$y'(x_m) \approx \frac{Y_{m+1} - Y_{m-1}}{2\Delta x},$$
$$y(x_m) \approx Y_m,$$
I get 
$$\frac{Y_{m-1} - 2Y_m + Y_{m+1}}{\Delta x^2} + \frac{x_m}{\Delta x}Y_m(Y_{m+1}-Y_{m-1}) - 2Y_m^2 = g(x_m).$$
However, the answer is supposed to be 
[image]

Why is the second term in my answer wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second version they are using a finite difference representation of the term $y^2$:

$$
(y^2)' \approx \frac{y^2_{m + 1} - y^2_{m - 1}}{2\Delta x} \tag{1}
$$

While you are using a finite representation of $2y y'$:

$$
2y y' \approx 2y_m\frac{y_{m + 1} - y_{m - 1}}{2\Delta x} \tag{2}
$$

But they are equivalent, if you take (if the solution $y$ is smooth enough you can do approximate the value at a node with the average of its neighbor nodes)

$$
y_m \approx \frac{y_{m + 1} + y_{m - 1}}{2} \tag{3}
$$

Then Eq. (2) becomes

$$
2yy' \approx 2y_m\frac{y_{m + 1} - y_{m - 1}}{2\Delta x} \approx (y_{m + 1} + y_{m - 1})\frac{y_{m + 1} - y_{m - 1}}{2\Delta x} = \frac{y^2_{m + 1} - y^2_{m - 1}}{2\Delta x} \approx (y^2)'
$$